# C++ use after move: Valid use-case?

Tags: c++, move

A simple question, is it legal to use an object, which owns a unique pointer, after it was moved, and continue working with the unique pointer in case it wasn't moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard guarantees that a moved-from `unique_ptr` does compare equal to `nullptr`. N4659 [unique.ptr]/4:

> Additionally, `u` can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer `u2`. Upon completion of such a transfer, the following postconditions hold:
>
> - (4.1) `u2.p` is equal to the pre-transfer `u.p`,
> - (4.2) `u.p` is equal to `nullptr`, and
> - (4.3) if the pre-transfer `u.d` maintained state, such state has been transferred to `u2.d`.

These guarantees also imply that it's safe to move from one that's already been moved from.

Comment: I failed to find this description in N4741... http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#4

Comment: @songyuanyao It is phrased differently but amounts to the same thing

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm But it doesn't say the `unique_ptr` being moved from will be set to `nullptr` explicitly.

Comment: @songyuanyao In N4741, this is guaranteed via the Postconditions for the move constructor, move assignment, and move-like constructor and assignment from a different specialization. For example, the constructor `unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;` has a postcondition `u.get() == nullptr`.

Comment: @aschepler feel free to edit my post to include the post-C++17 wording changes